# C++ #include not working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, include

I have been using Visual Studio and I think I must have messed with some setting. I can't include basic things like `<iostream>`. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // OpenCV window I/O

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

All the above lines are in red squiggle below. My guess is while trying to configure Visual Studio to use OpenCv, I messed with some setting.

Comment: What makes you think you `can't include basic things like <iostream>`? Do you have a specific error message ? We don't have enough information.

Comment: please show your code and your error message. And if your code has includes before stdafx.h, then that is your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely, you forgot to add 'using namespace std' as pretty much nothing in iostream is really useful without it. If you are getting 'cant find ...', then you have a setup problem and should reinstall Visual Studio because the headers were not properly placed.

Hope this helps, feel free to post your code and I can tell you for sure what the problem is, but that is the most likely of them.

Comment: Um, `using namespace std` is a sledgehammer that should never be used. If the problem is missing `std::` qualifiers on names that are defined in `<iostream>` the solution is to add the qualifiers. But with no code in the question that's just guessing.

Comment: @PeteBecker that is purely opinion, and I would agree in some cases. But for a small amount of code like this, it does not make that much difference. But, for reference, if you use cout, cin, string, etc you should either do 'using std::cin'... or just std::cin. I am a C programmer at heart, so I don't do namespaces often.

Comment: No, it's not purely opinion. We went to a great deal of trouble to put library names into their own namespace in order to avoid conflicts in the global namespace. Jamming everything into the global namespace is a bad idea.

Comment: @PeteBecker this is getting too off topic, so lets try and stop doing it on here, you may email me if you wish to continue. But "We went to a great deal of trouble ... Jamming everything in the global namespace is a bad idea" is an opinion. I have honestly never needed namespaces, and therefore do not believe they should be specifically applied, that is my opinion. The OP has the option to use my code or yours, depending on his/her beliefs.

Comment: That is not my problem. Can you concentrate on the problem please!

Comment: the rest is just test code from OpenCv to make sure it was configured to work correctly. Thing is even codes which used to work don't work now.

Comment: Try re-installing VS, it will fix any include problems you have with the actual files, and if that does not work, try resetting the IDE settings. Compile it from the command line to see if that works too

Comment: well re-installing will work. I just thought if there was an easy way. Thanks for the help.